# How to convert an Oracle timestamp object into a php date?

Tags: php, oracle, date

The date data is like this

```
09-OCT-12 03.19.59.000000000 PM
```

and it is coming from an object:

```
$objectvar->datedata;
```

I've tried this

```
$date = new DateTime($objectvar->datedata);
echo $date->format('M d,Y');
```

it doesn't work, it doesn't display the correct data from the object;

I've also tried this

```
echo date('M d,Y',strtotime($objectvar->datedata));
```

it doesn't work too, like it doesn't display the correct data from the object;

what can I do to correctly convert the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i've found the correct answer

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($objectvar->date);
$converteddate = $date->format('M d,Y');
echo $converteddate;
```

Answer (score 3):

This answer should be here:

```
$dt = DateTime::createFromFormat("d#M#y H#i#s*A", $objectvar->datedata);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a native way of doing it, but maybe you can use this method instead in the meanwhile:

```
list($day,$month,$year) = sscanf($objectvar->datedata,"%d-%s%-%d");
```

now you ca use it to create your date format

```
echo date("M d, Y",strtotime("$year-$month-$day"));
```